After the visited links color change, I can’t easily see the badges I've earned
After this was announced recently, I can’t even see what badge did I earn on this site actually, see the picture below:
P.S. This only happens in the badge I have visited, other badges look like OK.



Purple is just a bit lighter than black color, and that is the root cause of this issue.
I hope the staffs make changes with this issue. And use the original white color for the font. Or else, the word is unreadable!
In Mathematics Stack Exchange, the fonts of the badge appears in blue color:



In English Language Learners Stack Exchange, the fonts of the badge appears in very dark green:




I don't actually see this problem on your profile anymore. Do you still see this issue?

@Spevacus You need to visit the badge first.

D'oh. I thought I had, but I certainly had not. Ignore me.

At least here it's blue on gray, on SO meta it's black (or dark gray) and disappears completely. Well done on testing, as usual :D

Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/431247/3962537 -- on some sites, usernames whose profile you visited no longer look like links at all.

Thanks for reporting, we have a fix for this that's in progress right now. We're looking into the other issues as well. The .badge class needed extra attention.

Plot twist: this is done on purpose to give us a way to earn easy rep. But seriously, this is annoying because it used to be better. These days almost every bug fix results in at least one other, new, bug.

Lol. Is this a recent change? Because I also noticed that today and asked the same question. Then my question was marked as duplicate because this question was asked yesterday! Oh yes, I see the comment of @Carrott

@user1176409 FYI, my related Visited chat info page buttons now have a dark background color, making them hard to read question also got a downvote at around the same time. Thus, it may have been the same person who downvoted your question, with both downvotes being for basically the same reason, whatever that is.

This issue is now status-completed and fixed.
See the fonts of the badge that I visited recently:



The font is in white color now, not the weird color like in each site previously.
